# Component to take all available height with Flexbox (in Quasar/Vue)

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, quasar-framework

I'm building a component with header/main content/ footer where the main content will be scrollable. While I can do this in Js, I need the component to take all available space on height and footer to be at the bottom.
I can't get it to take the whole height, even if the code is correct.

Here is a pen with the not-working code: https://codepen.io/SharpBCD/pen/MNgxgY

```
    .panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;

    justify-content: flex-start; /* align items in Main Axis */
    align-items: stretch; /* align items in Cross Axis */
    align-content: stretch; /* Extra space in Cross Axis */

    background-color: #00acc1;
  }
   .panel-header{
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    /*max-height: fit-content;*/
  }
  .panel-main{
    /*margin-bottom: auto;*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1; /* same as flex: 1 1 auto; */
    justify-content: flex-start; /* align items in Main Axis */
    align-items: stretch; /* align items in Cross Axis */
    align-content: stretch; /* Extra space in Cross Axis */
    background-color: #0d47a1;
  }
  .panel-footer{
    margin-top: auto;
    max-height: fit-content;
  }
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the working code that I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/LmYay/

```
.flexbox-parent
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    justify-content: flex-start; /* align items in Main Axis */
    align-items: stretch; /* align items in Cross Axis */
    align-content: stretch; /* Extra space in Cross Axis */

    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.flexbox-item-grow
{
    flex: 1; /* same as flex: 1 1 auto; */
}
.fill-area
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    justify-content: flex-start; /* align items in Main Axis */
    align-items: stretch; /* align items in Cross Axis */
    align-content: stretch; /* Extra space in Cross Axis */

}
```

So... what's the problem? What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the flex model and lay your #q-app on the whole height of the window, you need to start building the flex layout from the root.

you can use the following styles :

```
 /* update */
#q-app {
  height:100vh;/* or min-height:100vh if you want it to grow */
  display:flex;
}
.q-pa-md{
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
 /* end update */
```

Demos *(snippet to run or forked codepens)*:

```css
/* update */
body {
  margin:0;
  }
#q-app {
  min-height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  }
.q-pa-md{
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  }
 /* end update */
.panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow:1; 
    
    justify-content: flex-start; /* align items in Main Axis */
    align-items: stretch; /* align items in Cross Axis */
    align-content: stretch; /* Extra space in Cross Axis */
  
    background-color: #00acc1;
  }
.panel-header{
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    /*max-height: fit-content;*/
  }
  .panel-main{
    /*margin-bottom: auto;*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1; /* same as flex: 1 1 auto; */
    justify-content: flex-start; /* align items in Main Axis */
    align-items: stretch; /* align items in Cross Axis */
    align-content: stretch; /* Extra space in Cross Axis */
    background-color: #0d47a1;
  }
  .panel-footer{
    margin-top: auto;
    max-height: fit-content;
  }
```

```html
<!--
  Forked from:
  https://quasar.dev/layout/grid/column#Example--Equal-Height-Example
-->
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <p> irelevant text to ocupy space before panel</p>
      <div class=" panel">
        <div class=" panel-header">
          I'm a header
        </div>
        <div class = "panel-main">
          Main content
        </div>
        <div class=" panel-footer">
          I'm a footer
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or  play with the fork https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RXbmYj

another version with overflow to keep footer at bottom and let main content scroll https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rXBgRV

Comment: this is a nice idea but in real app I can't work my way up to the root. This is a component that can be used in various places and I can't control what's above it.

Any other idea? Using JS is not a problem, I use it anyway.

Answer (score 8):

## Give responsibility to the parent

Making the component responsible for taking the whole space has not been successful for me without extra tinkering. A simpler solution is to use the `items-stretch` class for a `row`, then put a `col` in to be streched.
This might be more intuitive for others.

Shown below with `q-card` as an example. This should work with whatever child component you choose, provided you use appropriate `row` / `col` classes.

```html
<q-page id="addressesOverview" class="q-pa-md row items-stretch">
  <q-card class="col-12">
    <q-card-section> ... </q-card-section>
  </q-card>
</q-page>
```

If you have a common component to display the `q-page`, you can change it to `:class` and add the `items-stretch` class dynamically.

Link: [Quasar Docs - Flexbox - Alignment](https://quasar.dev/layout/grid/introduction-to-flexbox#Alignment)

Comment: `row` and `items-strech` on the `q-page` did the trick, and I think that the approach to set the size from the parent is the correct one. 
I used a div inside the page, so I also set that child's div to `row` and `width:100%`

Comment: Upvote this response worked for me, too.  Bypassed the extra `div class='row'` and simply set the `q-page` to `class='row'`.

Answer (score 0):

simply your `<html>` and `<body>`  were not occupying the whole page and the same for the children nodes ...just add this to your css :

```
html,body,#q-app,.q-pa-md {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Dadboz/pen/VoZNwR)

Comment: this makes the `.panel` to have the equivalent of 100vh. Try multiplying the `<p> irrelevant text to occupy space before panel</p>` and see how it works. I've updated the pen.
Also, as a component in the real app, I have other and more parents until the root so I'm looking for another approuch. JS may work?